# Pandas apply function to subset of rows

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am setting a column of a pandas dataframe to all zeros initially, and then using `apply` to populate a subset of this column. However, after attempting to do so, all values in the column still remain as zero.

This is how I am calling the apply function:

```
predictions['score'] = 0.0
predictions.loc[tickers]['score'] = predictions.loc[tickers]['prediction'].apply(calculate_score, args=(min, max))
```

where `tickers` is a subset of the indices in `predictions`, and `calculate_score(value, min, max)` is a function that returns a non-zero value.

Comment: you don't get a warning?

Comment: No, nothing. Should there be a warning or are you just asking if any is given?

Comment: Surprisingly I'm not getting a `SettingWithCopyWarning` when I just created a test. Though it's almost certainly the issue  here. You need to avoid chained assignment `][` and instead should use `.loc[tickers, 'score']` to subset your `DataFrame`

Comment: you should get a warning for using `.loc[tickers]['score']`

Comment: @ALollz it's quite interesting, no?

Comment: the simple debug would be to just print to console the result of `predictions.loc[tickers]['prediction'].apply(calculate_score, args=(min, max))`

Comment: @ALollz I see, thank you. And just out of interest is it ok to do something like `df.loc['col'].iloc[0]`

Comment: @KOB I think that is still problematic. You are first subsetting the `DataFrame` and then subsetting that subset, so the original object will not be modified.